# CleverTap iOS SDK AccountID/Token not working

Tags: ios, sdk, analytics, clevertap

So the AccountID and Token works as long as I put it in the info.plist file, but not for other plist files. I need to put it in our Environment.plist file to configure CleverTap for different environments. Is there a way to do this? I have tried CleverTap.instance(with: ) and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Clevertap framework will pick the AccountID & Token from target plist file.
If you want to make two different configurations i.e. one for test & another for production, Create another target for TEST. It will create one more plist.  You can update your TEST AccountID & Token in this.

While building don't forget to select the proper target.  Hoping this answers to your question.